# Problema con rutas anidadas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo la siguiente ruta anidada:

```
resources :companies do
  resources :weeks do
    resources :payrolls 
  end
end
```

Mi problema surge cuando realizo un `new_company_week` ya que ignora mi respuesta.

En el controlador tengo lo siguiente:

```
def new
  @week = Week.new
end

def create
  @week = Week.where('status_id = 1 and company_id = ?',params[:company_id]).update_all(status_id:4)
  @week = Week.new(week_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @week.save

      if(params[:company_id] == 4)
        @employees = EmployeeCw.all.where(status_id: 1)

        @employees.find_each do |employee|
          @payroll = Payroll.new({:employee_id=>employee.Employee.id, :week_id=>@week.id, :department_id=>employee.department_id,
          :dias_trabajados=>0,:dias_vacaciones=>0,:faltas=>0,:total_percepciones=>0,:total_retenciones=>0,
          :total_sueldo_bruto=>0,:total_sueldo_neto=>0,:sueldo_fiscal=>0,:pago_impuesto=>0,
          :pago_eps=>0,:tipo_pago_fiscal=>employee.tipo_pago_fiscal,:tipo_pago_eps=>employee.tipo_pago_eps,
          :created_by=> current_user,:updated_by=>current_user, :employee_cw=> employee.id})
          @payroll.save

          @employee_wd = EmployeeWd.new({:created_at=>current_user,:created_by=>current_user, :payroll_id=>@payroll.id,
          :construction_work=>employee.construction_work_id,:jueves=>0,:viernes=>0,:sabado=>0,:domingo=>0,
            :lunes=>0,:martes=>0,:miercoles=>0})
          @employee_wd.save

          flash[:notice] = "Week successfully created CHS"
          format.html { redirect_to company_weeks_path(params[:company_id])}
        end
      else
        @employees = Employee.all.where(status_id: 1)

        @employees.find_each do |employee|
          @payroll = Payroll.new({:employee_id=>employee.id, :week_id=>@week.id, :department_id=>employee.department_id,
          :dias_trabajados=>0,:dias_vacaciones=>0,:faltas=>0,:total_percepciones=>0,:total_retenciones=>0,
          :total_sueldo_bruto=>0,:total_sueldo_neto=>0,:sueldo_fiscal=>0,:pago_impuesto=>0,
          :pago_eps=>0,:tipo_pago_fiscal=>employee.tipo_pago_fiscal,:tipo_pago_eps=>employee.tipo_pago_eps,
          :created_by=>current_user,:updated_by=>current_user})
          @payroll.save

          @employee_wd = EmployeeWd.new({:created_at=>'Daniel',:created_by=>'daniel', :payroll_id=>@payroll.id,
          :jueves=>0,:viernes=>0,:sabado=>0,:domingo=>0,:lunes=>0,:martes=>0,:miercoles=>0})
          @employee_wd.save

          flash[:notice] = "Week successfully created"
          format.html { redirect_to company_weeks_path(params[:company_id])}
        end
      end
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @week.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
    end
  end
end
```

La verdad no sé si sea la forma más óptima de guardar información, sin embargo tengo la siguiente línea:

```
format.html { redirect_to company_weeks_path(params[:company_id]) }
```

La cual me ignora completamente y cuando hace el post me envía a `/weeks`.

En mis rutas tengo lo siguiente:

```
    company_weeks GET    /companies/:company_id/weeks(.:format)            weeks#index
                  POST   /companies/:company_id/weeks(.:format)            weeks#create
 new_company_week GET    /companies/:company_id/weeks/new(.:format)        weeks#new
edit_company_week GET    /companies/:company_id/weeks/:id/edit(.:format)   weeks#edit
     company_week GET    /companies/:company_id/weeks/:id(.:format)        weeks#show
                  PATCH  /companies/:company_id/weeks/:id(.:format)        weeks#update
                  PUT    /companies/:company_id/weeks/:id(.:format)        weeks#update
                  DELETE /companies/:company_id/weeks/:id(.:format)        weeks#destroy
```

Agrego una imagen con el error que me muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi metodo week_params es este:

```
def week_params
  params.require(:week).permit(:fecha_inicial, :fecha_final, :fecha_pago, :tipo_nomina, :created_by, :updated_by, :company_id)
end
```

Y los errores usando el params son los siguientes:
[image: Este es el request]

Comment: Probablemente esté generando un error al guardar la semana en `@week.save` y por eso no llega nunca al `redirect_to`. ¿Te muestra algun error en los logs?

Comment: Las inserciones las realiza sin problemas, el unico problema es en el redireccionamiento, el error que me sale es:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError (No route matches {:action=>"index", :company_id=>nil, :controller=>"weeks"} missing required keys: [:company_id]):

Esto pasa porque en la ruta que se refresca en la barra de direcciones se convierte en '/weeks' en lugar de '/companies/1/weeks' que es lo que requiero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No te redirecciona debido a que primero se genera un error (el que ves en tu pantalla) y, por lo tanto, te quedas en `/weeks`.

El error se debe a que `params[:company_id]` no trae ningún valor pues el parámetro lo envías dentro del grupo `week`, entonces `params[:company_id]` equivale a `nil` y de ahí el mensaje:

```
No route matches {:action=>"index", :company_id=>nil, :controller=>"weeks"}
```

Para solucionarlo cambia `params[:company_id]` por `params[:week][:company_id]`<sup>1</sup>:

```
format.html { redirect_to company_weeks_path(params[:week][:company_id]) }
```

<sup>1</sup> *También podrías utilizar `week_params[:company_id]`*

Comment: El detalle esta en que el request si me muestra que el parametro company_id se esta enviando ya que tambien me realiza las inserciones, pero en algún momento dentro del controlador lo estoy perdiendo y no se como almacenarlo ya que utilice variables y no me deja utilizarlas o cuando me deja usarlas me lo muestra nulo.

Comment: @DanielRomero ¿En la pantalla de error (la que muestras en tu pregunta, pero se corta) puedes ver el parámetro asignado correctamente? (Tu código hace inserciones aunque no traigas valor en el parámetro `company_id`.)

Comment: ahorita lo solucione haciendo esto   
def new
    
    @@company = params[:company_id]
    @week = Week.new
  end --- sin embargo no creo que sea una optima solución, a no ser que me digas lo contrario pero en el hash que se envia el parametro de company_id va correctamente con su valor.

Comment: Que bien! Aunque no deberías necesitar utilizar variables de clase (i.e. `@@company`) para ello.

Comment: Es que no se que hacer, porque las variables de instancia no me estan funcionando cuando las uso me manda la direccion de la variable en lugar de su valor, y si uso directamente el params dice que esta vacio, se que estoy cometiendo algún error pero no logro localizarlo.

Comment: @DanielRomero ¿Me puedes mostrar tu método `week_params`?

Comment: Ya actualice mi pregunta @Gerry con los datos que se me reflejan.

Comment: @DanielRomero me parece que ya vi el error: estás utilizando `params[:company_id]` en lugar de `params[:week][:company_id]`. Ahora actualizaré mi respuesta.

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, la respuesta fue con el params[:week][:company_id], ya que con weeks_path me manda a /weeks y me manda error ya que company_id la marca nil.

Comment: como puedo hacer para eliminar utilizando el delete de la ruta anidada?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo utilizando la ruta `company_week_path` con dos parámetros: `company_week_path(company_id, week_id)`, pero debes llamarla con el método `DELETE`.  Por ejemplo, desde tu vista podrías poner `<%= link_to "Borrar", company_week_path(@company.id, @week.id), :confirm => "Estas seguro?", :method => :delete %>` (considerando que `@company` y `@week` ya fueron creadas en el controlador previamiente).

Comment: Te agradezco mucho @Gerry solucionado todo por el momento